# Fermi theory of allowed beta decay

Tags: nuclear-physics

In Fermi theory of allowed beta decay, when we consider coulomb correction for the electronic wave functions then the coulomb correction increases the probability of electron emission and decreases the probability of positron emission. Why?

Since the electron and positron have an opposite charge but of the same magnitude, then they should feel the same coulombic force, but then it contradicts the above statement?

Also in beta negative decay, why there is a certain number of electrons with zero energy and in beta positive decay there are none positrons with zero energy?
[image]

Comment: Hint: consider the charge of the nucleus.

Comment: In beta negative decay, the daughter nucleus has one more proton than parent nucleus, and it will apply more coulombic attraction force on electron. So it should decrease the probability of electron emission, but why then probability of emission of electron increases?